# How can I pass a parameter using numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to use numpy with objects and to run the functions I have been trying to use the `numpy.vectorize` function and it works great but I don't know how to pass parameters through the code for example

```
import numpy as np
class ex:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b

   def exfunc(self, c):
       print(c)

str = "hi"
lis =np.array([ex() for x in range(10)])    
exvec = np.vectorize(ex.exfunc, otypes=[object])
```

now i dont know how this would be done but I would like to be able to pass a pram like this `exvec(lis,str)` but this doesn't work so I would to know how I can do something similar to what I just shown Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want those parameters to be 'vectorized' (iterated), either make them "globals", or use the 'exclude' mechanism.

Comment: I tried making the variable global but in the context I'm using it in I need it to work in a loop and for some reason it wouldn't update @hpauji

Comment: What you posted gives me a type error.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq my fault just put in 2 args in `lis =np.array([ex("a","b") for x in range(10)])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify parameters to be "externally" passed (excluded from filling
from the source array), pass *excluded* parameter to *np.vectorize* with
a list of strings - names of parameters of the vectorized function.

An example:

1. Source array:

   ```
    a = np.array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jko'])
   ```
2. The function to be vectorized:

   ```
    def myConcat(t1, t2):
        return t1 + '_' + t2
   ```

   You want *t2* to be passed "externally" (and *t1* filled from
   the underlying array).
3. Generate the vectorized function:

   ```
    myConc = np.vectorize(myConcat, excluded=['t2'])
   ```
4. Call this function:

   ```
    myConc(a, 'xx')
   ```

The result is:

```
array(['abc_xx', 'def_xx', 'ghi_xx', 'jko_xx'], dtype='<U6')
```

And a note about your code: The result is empty, since your function
(*exfunc*) only prints its argument, but does not return anything.

And a modified example based on your class:

```
class ex:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def exfunc(self, c):
        print(c)
        return self.a + '_' + c + '_' + self.b

# Array of "ex" objects
lis = np.array([ex('a' + str(x), 'b' + str(x)) for x in range(10)])
# Create vectorized version of "exfunc"
exvec = np.vectorize(ex.exfunc, otypes=[object], excluded=['c'])
# Run this function
exvec(lis, np.array(['h0', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'h7', 'h8', 'h9']))
```

Note that now *exfunc* returns something.

The result is:

```
h0
h1
h2
h3
h4
h5
h6
h7
h8
h9

array(['a0_h0_b0', 'a1_h1_b1', 'a2_h2_b2', 'a3_h3_b3', 'a4_h4_b4',
       'a5_h5_b5', 'a6_h6_b6', 'a7_h7_b7', 'a8_h8_b8', 'a9_h9_b9'],
      dtype=object)
```